# Script that takes an array and produces the next number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Python Program that takes an array of numbers as input and outputs the next number as output (Interview Questions).

Suppose I take an input:
array a=`[1,2,3.4]` or a=`[9,9,9]`

The output should be:
array b=`[1,2,3,5]` and `[1,0,0,0]`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Why is the next number for `[9,9,9]` → `[1,0,0,0]`? What's the rule and where's your own attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understood his question, he wants to make something like a manual counter that increments by 1 each time and when all digits reach 9 the next number should have one more digit here is an example :
[9,9,8] then [9,9,9] then [1,0,0,0] then [1,0,0,1] and so on.

Here is my attempt :

```
def nextNumber(array):

    if array[len(array) - 1] == 9:
       if len(array) == 1:
           return [1,0]
       else:
           return nextNumber(array[:-1]) + [0] 
    else:
       array[len(array) - 1] += 1 
       return array
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out the solution that i wanted myself

import array as arr

list=[]

num=int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))

for i in range(0,num):
ele = int(input())

```
list.append(ele)
```

print(list)

str1=""

for i in range(0,len(list)):
str1+=str(list[i])

print (str1)

fin=int(str1)+1
print(fin)

finstr= str(fin)

for i in range(0,len(finstr)):
res=[int(x) for x in str(finstr)]
print(res)